# Python WebService Client UTF-8 and special chars

Tags: python, web-services, utf-8

As with both suds and pysimplesoap requests, when I try to send a request with some UTF-8 special chars in it, the answer is that ascii codec cannot decode byte. With SoapUI no such problems, WebService returns correct answer. Here's the code:

```
def check_customer_via_reference(self, reference):
    wsdl_service = Client(http://localhost:81/localService/Service.svc?wsdl)
    xml = Raw("""
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:wcf="http://localService">
                   <soapenv:Header/>
                   <soapenv:Body>
                      <wcf:GetCode>
                         <wcf:Par1>test</wcf:Par1>
                         <wcf:Code>ąęźżć</wcf:Code>
                      </wcf:GetCode>
                   </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
    """)
    result = wsdl_service.service.GetCode(__inject={'msg': xml})
```

That code will return

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 380: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Whereas SoapUI will return

```
<a:Code>0</a:Code>
```

Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Raw` object with `unicode` string.

```
xml = Raw(u"""
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:wcf="http://localService">
                   <soapenv:Header/>
                   <soapenv:Body>
                      <wcf:GetCode>
                         <wcf:Par1>test</wcf:Par1>
                         <wcf:Code>ąęźżć</wcf:Code>
                      </wcf:GetCode>
                   </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
    """)
```

Comment: That didn't help as much as I thought. Looks like the answer to that question is not using Raw and passing it just as a regular str without declaring unicode string.